# IPhone set Text of button and also the position of the text

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I would like to ask how to set the text of a button whilst also specifying the position and colour of the mentioned text.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Lily

Have a look at the [UIButton Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html).

To set the Title value use `– setTitle:forState:` to set the title color `– setTitleColor:forState:`.

To change the position of the title, you need to configure the property `titleEdgeInsets`.